# Tomcat and request mapping

Tags: tomcat, servlets, spring-mvc

I have got stuck with a simple webapp.

After other complexer examples are failed to run, trying to test a sample app that i found here:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/

I am trying to run it under Tomcat, therefore i have only changed

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

to

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/samplejsp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

After deploying to Tomcat i have tried to get the welcome page on the web browser, but all i see is:
"HTTP Status 404" for "http://localhost:8080/samplejsp/", "http://localhost:8080/samplejsp/welcome", "http://localhost:8080/welcome/".

Trying to debug the servlet with Eclipse have not helped, eclipse connects to tomcat, but  nothing happens and the breakpoint remains untouched at requesting the mentioned urls.

Tomcat shows the app as deployed and running.

I suppose i do not get something about request mapping but i have no more ideas. Thanks for help and sorry for referring an external page.

Comment: What is the behaviour with the first configuration?

Comment: I have tried that out and requested "http://localhost:8080/welcome", the behaviour is the same.

Comment: What is the context path for your web application? If you are auto-deploying via WAR file or expanded-WAR directory, then it will be the name of the WAR (with the .war) extension, or "" (empty) if the name is ROOT.war (or "ROOT" if it is a directory).

Answer (score 0):

The `<url-pattern>` is relative to the web-app, not the Tomcat server.

If you specifiy something like `<url-pattern>/samplejsp/*</url-pattern>` and your application is installed at `/samplejsp` the servlet will reside at: `http://localhost:8080/samplejsp/samplejsp/`

Fore more information see the Oracle documentation for [web.xml Deployment Descriptor Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1015060).

Answer (score 0):

The `<url-pattern>` in servlet mapping should not contain the application context root.

Change `<url-pattern>/samplejsp/*</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`